# Not able to clear TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I enter the number both on a and b, suppose 58 and 78 in the text field.
And then when I go back to clear the number a, and come to number b, the number a value shows up with 5 instead of 0, is there anyway I can get this fixed to show a 0 value when the number is cleared instead of showing 5?
Here's is the code.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var a = Double()
    @State var b = Double()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Number 1")
            TextField("Enter Number 1", value: $a, format: .percent)
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Number 2")
            TextField("Enter Number 2", value: $b, format: .percent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The values bound to the text field have the type `Double` and they can't ever be empty.

Here's what happens:

1. You type `"58"` into the text field. The binding from the text field to the state var updates its value to `58.0`.
2. You erase the 8, the value of the text field becomes `"5"` and the state var gets updated with the new value of `5.0`.
3. You erase the remaining digit of 5, the value of the text field becomes `nil`. SwiftUI tries updating the state var with the value of `nil`, but it can't because its type is `Double`, so the state var keeps the previous value of `5.0`.
4. You move the focus to the next text field. SwiftUI re-renders the views and the first text field gets updated with the value of its bound state var, which is 5.

To fix it, change the type of the state vars to optional:

```swift
@State var a: Double?
@State var b: Double?
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, I was pondering this one myself, happy to see a solution

Comment: But how do you display this in a Text. Text('\(a)') won't work?? You get this error: No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'

Comment: You can nil-coalesce that to zero: `Text("\(a ?? 0.0)")`.

Comment: But the app would crash if you multiply c = a* b and if one of the value is empty?? How do we fix this?? While with the other method it would at least give the value of c = something as there will be some variable be it a 0 or some value.

Comment: It won't crash because `c = a * b` won't even compile while `a` and `b` have the type of `Double?` because the multiplication operation is not defined for optional Doubles. You'll have to nul-coalesce both `a` and `b` to zero before multiplying them. Like this: `Text("a × b = \((a ?? 0) * (b ?? 0))")`. That's a bit cumbersome I agree and you can probably write some wrappers around it, but that's out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var a: Double?
@State var b: Double?
@State var result : Double = 0.0

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Number 1")
        TextField("Enter Number 1", value: $a, format: .percent)
       
    }
    HStack {
        Text("Number 2")
        TextField("Enter Number 2", value: $b, format: .percent)
    }
    HStack {
        Button  {
            result = (a ?? 0.0) * (b ?? 0.0)
        } label: {
            Text("calculate a * b")
        }
        Text("\(result)")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your solution is any different to what I already proposed in my answer and in the comments to it.

Comment: I only gave him the code and extra sample Because he did not understand how to deal with multiply and ?? Operation.